# Angular: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a freshman in typescript.I wrote a table but it alarmed that

> ERROR in E:/internship/angular-demo/ngdemo/src/app/_services/task.service.ts (24,27): Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

I couldn't find the answer, so I've come to ask for a way to solve it.

Here is the code:

```
let params =new URLSearchParams();
params.set('User_id',t.User_id);
params.set('complete', t.complete);
params.set('summary', t.summary);
params.set('description', t.description);
return this.http
 .post(taskUrl, params)
 .map(response => 
response.json());
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have provided I am guessing that your `User_id` is an integer (number). Try adding `toString()` to the end of the `User_id` property.

```js
let params =new URLSearchParams();
params.set('User_id',t.User_id.toString());
params.set('complete', t.complete);
params.set('summary', t.summary);
params.set('description', t.description);
return this.http
 .post(taskUrl, params)
 .map(response => 
response.json());
```

If that's not it, then I may need a bit more information. Basically if this is truly where the error is originating from, you are probably trying to pass a number into the `URLSearchParams` object as one of the values.